# Local Kafka - ssl issue

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

My exception while starting kafka-server-start.bat ....\config\server-0.properties

```
[2022-04-07 17:30:05,514] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9095,SSL://localhost:9096
auto.create.topics.enable=false
ssl.keystore.location=C:/softwares/ssl/server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=abc123
ssl.key.password=abc123
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=

ssl.truststore.location=C:/softwares/ssl/server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=abc123
ssl.client.auth=required


transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2182
```

Comment: That's an info log, not an exception. You've clearly not configured Zookeeper for SSL (`listenerType=ZK_BROKER`) only Kafka

Comment: Zookeeper doesn't need SSL, but your clients do https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html

Comment: configured server.properties file as directed but no luck

Comment: No luck with what? Does the server actually crash, or you want to hide that log line?

Answer (score -1):

These are configurations that you have to make sure while running a command.

Check for a correct IP address and port combination passed in command bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.X.X:4848 --list
Main important point , configure listeners with IP address in server.properties correctly .

listeners=PLAINTEXT://**192.168.X.X:4848 --working**

listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:4848 --Not working

Post-change, restart kafka server.

Comment: listeners should by be bound to `0.0.0.0` or empty by default anyways, as to allow connections from non-local hosts. This answer confused me implying that they should be set to the server IP, disabling local connections.

Answer (score -1):

```
INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Failed authentication with /127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
```

...can be ignored (as @OneCricketeer mentions it's not an exception) and is unrelated to the issue. Kafka works despite it.